# How to get all the records from the Table A and only common records from table B in sql

Tags: sql

I have two tables Table A and Table B as follows.

```
  TableA:
   Id  name
    1    abc
    2    john
    3    jack
    4    jill

  Table B:
  Id  city     phn
   1  london    9876345
   5  bangalore 2345678 
   3  chennai   5637473
```

I want records which are present in tableA  but not in Table B.But the result should be

```
   TableA:
   Id  name
    1    abc
    2    john
    3    jack
    4    jill
```

i.e even though 1 and 3 ids are present in Table B but they are still in table A.I want those records too.

```
       5  bangalore 2345678
```

this records is not present in Table A.so i should not take this.

Comment: `select * from TableA` will give you the result you want.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson -- your query looks familiar :)

Comment: @sgeddes there must be some time distortion on my phone. There was no answers when I started writing. Or I write very slow :).

Comment: thanks for all ur answers.But can't we do this without using Joins.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson - LMAO :-)

Comment: @user1865384 -- seriously...

Comment: It is like Basket A has apples and Basket B has Oranges and apples.I want all apples from Basket A and apples from Basket B but not oranges.

Comment: @user1865384 That's not what your question says, nor is it how your example data is formed. With everything in the question, `select * from TableA` is pretty much the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need a left outer join.

Look into it here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL) and here: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp

EDIT:
Your question makes no sense to be honest. In the heading you mention: "All the values in A and only common values in B" and then, you go on to state in the explanation that you need values from 'A' only and not B.. for that

`select * from TableA` will do.

Comment: @TildalWave why did you downvote? I don't understand, my answer tells him what he needs to know. This will help someone later in time too.

Comment: @TildalWave the heading of the question does not correspond to the explanation at all. The heading states "All from A and only common from B"(which is typical Left Join) and in the explanation it states: "only in A and not in B". WTF is this question.. lol (changing my answer)

Comment: @TildalWave how SO users use this website is, they first see the heading, then they frame an understanding of the question and almost premeditate on the answer. I agree we _must_ read the description of the question. The heading, of this question however, corresponds directly to Left Outer Joins.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23676/discussion-between-aniket-and-tildalwave)

Comment: yeah thanks for removing the downvote, and a good load of chuckles and lols and rofls after reading the description :-P.. see ya!

Comment: Sry, if i frame the question wrongly. forexample,Basket A has apples and Basket B has Oranges and apples.my question is,I want all apples from Basket A and only apples from Basket B but not oranges.

Comment: @user1865384 your table A relates to table B directly. Obviously what's present in A will be present in B and some more too. `select * from TableA` will give you only those which are present in A but not in B. On the other hand, if you wanted from B only those records that are present in Table A, with their names, you can use an inner join.

Comment: ok..I want to write a query as follows..Iam new to SQL..please just guide if iam wrong...select * from tableA where condtion and id not in (select id from table B where condition).I want to put this query in this way...

Comment: @user1865384 this is incorrect query. That will first select all the ids from B matching the where condition, then it will select everything from A, filter out the ones which are common to both B and A with a specified condition, with a specific where condition for table A. What you get is a ball of bullshit.

Answer (score 2):

Really -- this simple?  Don't think you need any joins then...

```
SELECT * FROM TableA
```

Good luck.

Comment: Hehe -- me too -- funniest question I've answered all month :)